# Make Error: Map Server

Tags: linker, makefile, mapserver

**The Problem:**

I'm trying to install Mapserver-6.0.2 but I'm running into trouble when I compile the program with make. I tired looking up answers online and it seems people have similar trouble with other programs but their solutions don't make too much sense. Here is the error I get when I run make:

```
/bin/ld: note: 'FT_New_Face' is defined in DSO /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib64/libfreetype.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for your error message "could not read symbols: Invalid operation" led to [this email message](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2010-March/133601.html) which referenced these two Fedora wiki pages:

1. [Features/ChangeInImplicitDSOLinking](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ChangeInImplicitDSOLinking)
2. [UnderstandingDSOLinkChange](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/UnderstandingDSOLinkChange)

The second of which says:

> ```
> RPM build errors:
> /usr/bin/ld.bfd: rpmdumpheader.o: undefined reference to symbol 'Fopen'
> /usr/bin/ld.bfd: note: 'Fopen' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/librpmio.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
> /usr/lib/librpmio.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
> ```

and recommends a fix for that of:

> ```
> rpmdumpheader: rpmdumpheader.o
> -       $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -lrpm -o $@
> +       $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -lrpm -lrpmio -o $@
> ```

Or to paraphrase the email itself:

> In your case the solution would be to add [`-lfreetype`] to the linker line.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not very familiar with Makefiles, beyond very basic configurations. I did come across that site before but after fully reading through the guide I was able to edit Map Server's Makefile to compile fully.

Comment: You should report this to the MapServer authors as this is something they should fix in their source.

Comment: MapServer 6.0.2 is over 3 years old. Current version is 7.0, released just a few days ago. See http://mapserver.org/announcements_all.html